# Modern view and PageRenderType

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, modern-experience, modern-pages

I have a migrated list (from 2007) that I can't get to show in Modern mode. When I run this command to determine the PageRenderType, it gives me the result value 1 (MultipeWePart). What does this mean? What changes do I have to make to the list in order for it to render in Modern view?

```
GET _api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/dev/ECMTest/Forms/AllItems.aspx')/pageRenderType
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one view, possibly the default view, has two webparts. That can happen if someone used for example SharePoint Designer to modify the view. Try creating a new view from the web interface, set it as default and then delete all other views. You might even have to check for hidden views with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I found the details on the PageRenderType here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries

We've just received word that Classic pages will be deprecated over Christmas so I suspect what will happen, (if the view isn't compatible with Modern) is they will load in an IFrame similar to what Quick Edit does now in Modern. Ugly way to force everyone over